# How to search a list within a list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to search through lists within a list to find and change one of the items.

I want to be able to search the 0th and 1st item in the lists, and if they match my criteria I want to change/update the 2nd item.

I understand you can search using enumerate but am struggling to understand/write the coding for this.

```
myList = [['blue', 'house', 'go', 'no'],['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
```

I would like to be able to search the list for the 0th element being 'blue' and the 1st element being 'house', and then change the 2nd element to 'stop.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you do `for item in myList`, the local variable `item` will hold each inner list at each iteration. So in the first iteration, `item == ['blue', 'house', 'go', 'no']` and in the second iteration, `item == ['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']`. Now, you can check the 0th and 1st elements through `item[0]` and `item[1]`. Can you pick up from there? ;]

Comment: `for sublist in myList: if sublist[0] == 'blue' and sublist[1] == 'house': sublist[2] = 'stop'`

Answer (score 1):

You can slice `myList` so you can do both comparisons without using `and`

```
myList = [['blue', 'house', 'go', 'no'],['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
for m in myList:
    if m[:2] == ['blue', 'house']:
        m[2] = 'stop'
print(myList)

[['blue', 'house', 'stop', 'no'], ['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using list comprehension

```
>>> [e if e[: 2] != ['blue', 'house'] else (e[: 2] + ['stop'] + e[3: ]) for e in myList]
[['blue', 'house', 'stop', 'no'], ['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
```

Comment: This is certainly more concise and yields the same result, but replaces the list rather than updating it. With small lists, the distinction is probably unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop and checking both that the first element of the current inner list equals `blue` and the second element equals `house` explicitly might be the easiest to understand if you haven't learnt list slicing yet:

```
my_lists = [['blue', 'house', 'go', 'no'],['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
for inner_list in my_lists:
    if inner_list[0] == 'blue' and inner_list[1] == 'house':
        inner_list[2] = 'stop'
print(my_lists)
```

**Output:**

```
[['blue', 'house', 'stop', 'no'], ['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking for a cleaner solution:

```
myList = [['blue', 'house', 'go', 'no'],['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
result = [[*a, 'stop' if a == ['blue', 'house'] else b, c] for *a, b, c in myList]
```

Output:

```
[['blue', 'house', 'stop', 'no'], ['yellow', 'mansion', 'stop', 'yes']]
```